# How do you correctly initialize an array of structs in C?

Tags: c

If I were to run this program right here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct member
{
  char firstname[30];
  char lastname[30];
  char phone[10];
  int age;
};

int main()
{
  struct member members[] = {
      {
          "Martha",
          "Flores",
          "5576380918",
          20
      },
      {
          "Carolina",
          "Fuentes",
          "5510101010",
          21
      },
      {
          "Fernanda",
          "Ramos",
          "7778189054",
          23
      }};

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    printf("%s %s %s %d\n", members[i].firstname, members[i].lastname, members[i].phone, members[i].age);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To output is going to be as expected +  a weird character on the second result:

```
Martha Flores 5576380918 20
Carolina Fuentes 5510101010� 21
Fernanda Ramos 7778189054 23
```

Now, if I remove the field *age* from the structure and rewrite the program accordingly to get the same behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct member
{
  char firstname[30];
  char lastname[30];
  char phone[10];
  // int age;
};

int main()
{
  struct member members[] = {
      {
          "Martha",
          "Flores",
          "5576380918",
          // 20
      },
      {
          "Carolina",
          "Fuentes",
          "5510101010",
          // 21
      },
      {
          "Fernanda",
          "Ramos",
          "7778189054",
          // 23
      }};

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", members[i].firstname, members[i].lastname, members[i].phone);
    // printf("%s %s %s %d\n", members[i].firstname, members[i].lastname, members[i].phone, members[i].age);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I got this output:

```
Martha Flores 5576380918Carolina
Carolina Fuentes 5510101010Fernanda
Fernanda Ramos 7778189054���
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong initializing the array, I tried being more specific while initializing the elements on the array with {.firstname = "", .lastname="", ...} but got the same result.

I'm compiling it with GCC

Comment: Always be aware of the *"Too Short By One"* problem. It's better to be 1,000 characters too long, than 1 character to short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone numbers are actually 11 characters long, since they include the NUL terminating character (`'\0'`). You need to provide the proper amount of space.

For example, these two character strings are equivalent.

```
char n[] = "5576380918";
char m[] = { '5', '5', '7', '6', '3', '8', '0', '9', '1', '8', '\0' };
```

Simply provide more space for your phone numbers:

```
struct member {
    char firstname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    char phone[11];
    int age;
};
```

The random characters you are seeing is an indeterminable result of Undefined Behavior from reading past the end of your allocated space, since the `printf` function relies on strings to be properly NUL terminated.

Comment: That's correct, I completely forgot about the NULL character. Weird to see it affect things like that but makes sense.